# music player playlist

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.6, playlist, audio-player

i made a music player with a playlist but the songs in playlist are not playable because only the name of song is going in playlist not a complete mp3 file. can you tell me how to handle this problem??
here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import mp3play
import tkFileDialog
import Tkinter
import tkFont
import Tkinter as tk
#from PIL import ImageTk,Image

def open_file():                                #Opens a dialog box to open .mp3 file
    global music                                #then sends filename to file_name_label.
    global mp3
    global play_list
    filename.set (tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension = ".mp3", filetypes=[("All Types", ".*"), ("MP3", ".mp3")]))
    playlist = filename.get()
    playlist_pieces = playlist.split("/")
    play_list.set (playlist_pieces[-1])
    playl = play_list.get()
    play_list_display.insert(END, playl)
    mp3 = filename.get()
    print mp3
    music = mp3play.load(mp3)
    pieces = mp3.split("/")
    name.set (pieces[-1])

def play():                                     #Plays the .mp3 file
    music.play()

def stop():                                     #Stops the .mp3 file
    music.stop()                

def pause():                                    #Pauses or unpauses the .mp3 file
    if music.ispaused() == True:
        music.unpause()
    elif music.ispaused() == False:
        music.pause()

def vol(event):                                 #Allows volume to be changed with the slider
    v = Scale.get(volume_slider)
    music.volume(v)

def tune_changed(event):
    idx = event.widget.curselection()[0]
    print ("Now playing %s" % event.widget.get(idx))

def Exit():
    exit()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("EmoPlayer")

root.configure(background='black')

#root = Tk()

root.geometry('300x100+750+300')

filename = Tkinter.StringVar()
name = Tkinter.StringVar()
play_list = Tkinter.StringVar()
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg="black", fg="Orange")
menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu = filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label='Open', command = open_file)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label='Exit', command = Exit)
root.config(menu=menubar)
open_file = Button(root, width = 6, height = 1, text = 'Mood',fg='Orange', bg='black')
open_file.grid(row=0, column=3)
play_button = Button(root, width = 5, height = 1, text='Play', fg='Orange', command = play, bg="black")
play_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = W)
stop_button = Button(root, width = 5, height = 1, text='Stop',fg='Orange', command = stop, bg="black")
stop_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky = W)
pause_button = Button(root, width = 5, height = 1, text='Pause',fg='Orange', command = pause, bg="black")
pause_button.grid(row=0, column=2)
volume_slider = Scale(root, label='Volume', orient = 'horizontal', fg = 'Orange', command = vol, bg="black")
volume_slider.grid(row=0, column=4)
file_name_label = Label(root, font=('Comic Sans', 8), fg = 'Orange', wraplength = 300, textvariable=name, bg="black" )
file_name_label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=8)

play_list_window = Toplevel(root, height = 150, width = 100)
play_list_window.title("Playlist")
play_list_display = Listbox(play_list_window, selectmode=EXTENDED, width = 50, bg="Dark Slate grey", fg="Orange")
play_list_display.bind("<Double-Button-1>", tune_changed)

play_list_display.pack()

play_list_window.mainloop()



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look at your code because I haven't worked with mp3play before and thought it was interesting.

Here's what I changed:

1. I put your code in a class so that it's easier and cleaner to share variables between methods. It also removes the need to mess around with `global`. Generally cleaned up the code a bit, for example, breaking up excessively long lines. I tried not to change your code where it wasn't necessary though.
2. Added a `trackLocations` list that keeps the actual file paths.
3. Added a line that loads the new file on double clicking in the playlist

This was the result, I hope it helps:

```
from Tkinter import *
import mp3play
import tkFileDialog
import Tkinter
import tkFont
import Tkinter as tk

class musicplay:
    def __init__(self):
        self.music = None
        self.play_list = []
        self.trackLocations = []

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("EmoPlayer")

        self.root.configure(background='black')
        self.root.geometry('300x100+750+300')

        self.filename = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.name = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.play_list = Tkinter.StringVar()

        menubar = Menu(self.root)
        filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg="black", fg="Orange")
        menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu = filemenu)
        filemenu.add_command(label='Open', command = self.open_file)
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label='Exit', command = self.Exit)
        self.root.config(menu=menubar)

        open_file = Button(self.root, width = 6, height = 1,
                           text = 'Mood',fg='Orange', bg='black')
        open_file.grid(row=0, column=3)

        play_button = Button(self.root, width = 5, height = 1, text='Play',
                             fg='Orange', command = self.play, bg="black")
        play_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = W)

        stop_button = Button(self.root, width = 5, height = 1, text='Stop',
                             fg='Orange', command = self.stop, bg="black")
        stop_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky = W)

        pause_button = Button(self.root, width = 5, height = 1, text='Pause',
                              fg='Orange', command = self.pause, bg="black")
        pause_button.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.volume_slider = Scale(self.root, label='Volume',
                              orient = 'horizontal', fg = 'Orange', 
                              command = self.vol, bg="black")
        self.volume_slider.grid(row=0, column=4)

        file_name_label = Label(self.root, font=('Comic Sans', 8),
                                fg = 'Orange', wraplength = 300,
                                textvariable=self.name, bg="black")
        file_name_label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=8)

        play_list_window = Toplevel(self.root, height = 150, width = 100)
        play_list_window.title("Playlist")
        self.play_list_display = Listbox(play_list_window, selectmode=EXTENDED,
                                    width = 50, bg="Dark Slate grey",
                                    fg="Orange")
        self.play_list_display.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.tune_changed)
        self.play_list_display.pack()
        play_list_window.mainloop()

        self.root.mainloop()        

    def open_file(self):                                
        """
        Opens a dialog box to open .mp3 filemusic,
        then sends filename to file_name_label.
        """
        self.filename.set(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(
            defaultextension = ".mp3",
            filetypes=[("All Types", ".*"), ("MP3", ".mp3")]))
        self.playlist = self.filename.get()
        playlist_pieces = self.playlist.split("/")
        self.play_list.set (playlist_pieces[-1])
        playl = self.play_list.get()
        self.play_list_display.insert(END, playl)
        print self.filename.get()
        self.music = mp3play.load(self.filename.get())
        pieces = self.filename.get().split("/")
        self.trackLocations += [self.filename.get()]
        self.name.set(pieces[-1])

    def play(self):
        """Plays the .mp3 file"""
        self.music.play()

    def stop(self):
        """Stops the .mp3 file"""
        self.music.stop()                

    def pause(self):
        """Pauses or unpauses the .mp3 file"""
        if self.music.ispaused():
            self.music.unpause()
        else:
            self.music.pause()

    def vol(self, event):
        """Allows volume to be changed with the slider"""
        v = Scale.get(self.volume_slider)
        try:
            self.music.volume(v)
        except:
            pass

    def tune_changed(self, event):
        idx = event.widget.curselection()[0]
        self.music = mp3play.load(self.trackLocations[int(idx)])
        print ("Now playing %s" % event.widget.get(idx))

    def Exit(self):
        exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    musicplay()
```

Comment: Thank u so much ..it helped
i want to ask that what is the purpose of 'self'. why you used it in each line??
and is it possible to save those mp3 files paths, which are in playlist,  in an array ??and how to do it??

Comment: i also done with saving playlist. this player plays almost all songs but while playing few songs it gives me this error : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.' ... now i am unable to understand this error.

Answer (score 0):

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.'

I also struggled with this error after long google search i found on some German forum a post from some c++ guy who said it was because of ID3v2 tags with witch MCI has problems.

I then used mutagen - Python multimedia tagging library, to strip the tag from mp3 before playing it, since then i never encountered this error again. Also if resorting to mutagen make sure the mp3 file has write permission before stripping of its tag.